# Remove tag from master after merge

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-tag

Our release branch TAG got into master after a merge in the wrong direction. We prefer not to keep TAGs on master. 
How do I just remove the TAG from master but keep the other file commits intact?

```
release     master
|              |[time now]
|              |
|              |
|              |tag1(to remove)
|   >merge>    |
|              |
|tag1          |
|              |
|              |[time before]
```

Comment: What do you mean? Tags are not "into" branches, they are at the same level as branches: both are pointers to commits.

Comment: "$git describe"  on master gives me a tag name, which was undefined previously. I want it to receive undefined again.

Comment: If the tag references an ancestor of `release` and you merge `release` to `master` then the commit referenced by the tag will also be an ancestor of `master`. That's why `git-describe` shows that tag.

Comment: yes, and I want to remove the tag and keep all other merges since then intact, how could I do that

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a wrong perception of tags in Git. Branches and tags are both simply pointers to commits. The difference between the two is, that branches can be changed, tags can not, i.e., branches are writeable, tags are read-only so to say.

Tags do not exist on any branch, since they are, like branches, simply pointers. For a better understanding on branches please refer to the simple diagrams in the Git Book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

When you create a tag, let's call it `v1.0` it points to exactly one commit, let's say `ba70138`, i.e., `v1.0 --> ba70138`. This does not define whether or not this commit is reachable by any branch. It's the parent-child relations between commits which define the history. As soon as you merge your release branch to `master` it contains commit `ba70138` and therefore the tag `v1.0` is reachable from `master`.

See also documentation of `git describe`:

> git-describe - Describe a commit using the most recent tag reachable
>          from it